# Likert Survey Results

Tags: cognito-forms

I want to create a Likert-style survey (i.e., ranked answers). The survey will have questions that relate to seven categories. I'd like the results of the survey to be exported into a graph format (simple line graph or bar chart) with each bar on the graph corresponding to the total rank for the questions in each category.

To achieve this, the answers for the questions would need to have a numeric rank (e.g. "Not descriptive of me"=1; "Very descriptive of me"=5). Then the questions corresponding to each category could be totaled to give an overall total for each category.

I'd also then need to export the data into Excel or Word so that the data could be shared with the respondent.

Answer (score 0):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/) automatically assigns numerical values to the questions in the rating scale field. It also supports the ability to export form data into Excel; so once you've finished collecting your form entries, you can view the numerical values in Excel and manipulate the data into charts and graphs from there:

[image]